# Как сделать проверку на возможность подгрузки яндекс карты?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, yandex-maps-api

Есть сайт https://moneyavto.ru/

Без VPN не погружается яндекс карта и сайт виснит. Как сделать проверку если есть возможность подгрузить яндекс карту то подключить ее через скрипт

```
  if($("#map").length > 0) {
    var mapZoom = $("#map").attr("data-zoom");
    var lat = $("#map").attr("data-lat");
    var long = $("#map").attr("data-long");
    ymaps.ready(function () {        
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [long, lat],
            zoom: mapZoom
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });
        myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([long, lat], {
            hintContent: ''
        }, {
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark1);        
    });
  }
```

В консоле есть такая ошибка

```
jquery.js?ver=1.0:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: ymaps is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

Comment: `'ymaps' in window`

Comment: В норме недоступность API Яндекс Карт не подвешивает сайт, поскольку скрипт запускается только после загрузки API (ymaps.ready(init); В вашем случае подключается устаревшая версия API 2.0 без обязательного API-ключа. src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&#038;lang=ru-RU&#038;ver=1.0" Результат непредсказуем уже поэтому. Если это работа стороннего плагина, тем хуже. Если хотите помощи от специалистов по WordPress, указывайте это в тегах и полное описание ситуации в самом вопросе.